# SQL Select statement (from 2 different tables)

Tags: sql

Heyy I'm new to sql and I'd just like to know if there's a way to retrieve select statements with conditions from other tables.

I want to select all name values that have a number that identifies that they have committed a crime. I only want to select a name once.

```
"SELECT distinct * FROM  Table1 WHERE number LIKE table2.number "
```

Comment: Why `LIKE` ? Which RDBMS? What is table2 ?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Tip: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `IN`?

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.number IN (SELECT t2.number FROM table2 t2 t2.number);
```

Under most circumstances, the rows in a table should be unique.  So, you don't need `SELECT DISTINCT`.  The `DISTINCT` can add a considerable amount of overhead to such a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can able to use INNER JOIN like below,

```
select tbl1.Name from tableOne tbl1
inner join tableTwo tbl2 ON tbl1.commonKey = tbl2.commonKey
where tbl1.columnName = 'any value'
```